# StaticPagedList no divide la vista por los campos señalados

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Estoy usando [X.PagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) para realizar una paginación de unos objetos, en el controlador le asigno los objetos y utilizo StaticPagedList para crear la paginación. Pero en la vista me muestra todos los datos sin realizar la división:

### Vista

```
@foreach (var mod in ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts)
{
    <!--Esto muestra todos los resultados-->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class="product-content product-wrap clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="product-image alinear">
                        <img src="@mod.ImageUrl" alt="@mod.NumSerie" class="img-responsive">
                        <span class="tag2 hot">
                            @mod.Resultado
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<!--Realiza bien el conteo de páginas-->
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("NFF", new { page }))
```

### Controlador

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NFF(string Titulo, int? page)
{
    var pageIndex = (page ?? 1) - 1; //Pagina
    var pageSize = 6;

    var registros = _svcDatos.GetNFF().Select(ToVm).ToList(); //Llamada a BBDD con los registros
    
    var usersAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<RegistroConImagenVM>(registros, pageIndex + 1, pageSize, registros.Count());

    ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = usersAsIPagedList;

    return View("NFF", new RegistrosNFF() { Titulo = Titulo, Registros = registros });
}
```

Como se puede ver en la vista `PagedListPager` si que captura bien el máximo de elementos y realiza la paginación, pero el foreach no.

[image: Datos recibidos]

> #### ¿Por qué muestra todos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba cogiendo todos los elementos si usamos los elementos de `OnePageOfProducts.FirstItemOnPage` y `OnePageOfProducts.LastItemOnPage` en un for se soluciona el problema:

```
@for(int i = ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts.FirstItemOnPage - 1; i < ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts.LastItemOnPage; i++)
{
    //Bucle con los elementos
}
```